# Server wont let me save URLs to MySQL database?

Tags: web-hosting, apache-2.2, cms, mod-security

I am posting here because all other forum say it's a server environ issue.

I have a site with the ModX CMS on it hosted on a GoDaddy server (not sure about the specific setup is as client has forgotten login details). For some reason (mod_security?) I cannot save any string via the CMS that incorporates `http://` or `https://` to the MySQL database.

I've got similar sites (that are not hosted on GoDaddy) that work fine.

Is there some file or set up (Apache?) that blocks me from saving certain strings (URLs) to the MySQL database?

Video of problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqlZbckGEiA

Comment: Sounds more like a SQL issue. You should post the code and then we can migrate this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnConde thanks, but I have already asked on Stack Overflow. It isnt really a code question, more of a server environment set up or server security question. I've altered the question but am not sure how I can make it clearer than it is.

Comment: Ok, I'll reopen it and see what we get.

Comment: Just checkin but you've issued yourself a SQL instance? because GoDaddy doesn't use localhost, it uses a remote instance DB server.

Comment: @bybe thanks, yeah the SQL works fine - I've installed the CMS successsfully and can save all other content fine. Its only when I include the characters 'http://' that I get into trouble

Comment: Are you guessing that it's mod_security, or do you know that that's the issue?

Comment: @TimFountain I am guessing, based on what other (front end) forums have said

Comment: Then I'd suggest your next step would be to see if mod_security (which is an Apache module) is installed/enabled, see here: http://superuser.com/questions/284898/how-to-check-which-apache-modules-are-enabled-installed

Comment: Have you ruled out that it's not the CMS that is blocking this? What error are you actually getting? If it's mod_security I would think that it's more likely blocking a form submission that contains this data, rather than the actual INSERT/UPDATE to the database?

Comment: @w3d I'm very sure it is not the CMS. I've used the same CMS countless times on other servers and its fine. Yes it could defiantly be blocking a form submission as that is how the CMS works - submitting forms with page content that updates the DB.

Comment: What about ftp:// or just // itself or other similar strings. It may not be specific to http:// ?

Comment: Is the form being submitted by POST or GET? And you say the `http://` only has to be _part of_ a larger string submission? Presumably you are on a shared server? If it is a mod_security thing then this is not usually something that you have control over at an account/user level. (?)

Comment: @barrycarter just tried ftp:// then - same issue. // works though

Comment: @w3d it appears to be POST. It doesnt seem to matter where http:// is - it can be by itself or part of a larger string. Yep, it's a shared server. Im guessing Im just going to have to ring up and ask GoDaddy to have a look?

Comment: How about :// with no protocol? Dig around a bit to see if you can differentiate between what's blocked and what isn't. It could even just be the colon or something [insert 'blocked colon' joke here]

Comment: And what error are you getting exactly? @barrycarter lol

Comment: @barrycarter I tried `://` `test://` and `smtp://` it was happy with all of those

Comment: @w3d I dont get an error, the page just seems to be caught in an infinite loop. Ive attached a video above.

Comment: Ah OK, looks like an AJAX request (does the CMS not time out eventually with an error?). Are you able to check the network traffic in the Object Inspector? If it's mod_security, the server is likely blocking the request and simply returning a 406, or even 500 status code.

Comment: Try "http" by itself with no colon, and then try replacing the colon and/or slashes with `&#58;` and `&#47;` respectively.

Comment: @barrycarter it was fine with `http` and even `http:/` and `http:&#58;&#58;` so it must definitely be identifying the string `http://`

Comment: It sounds like you need to check the mod security rules in place. There are some default rules that disallow sql injections via http which I am sure you are running into. BTW- ModSecurity is an application that hooks into Apache and behaves like a module, but is not actually an Apache module per se'. https://www.modsecurity.org/